# Not being notified in Mailchimp when subscribers are added via Zapier

Tags: mailchimp, zapier

Normally, when a subscriber signs up though MailChimp you have the option to get an email:
[image]

I have this option turned on, however when a subscriber gets added through Zapier instead of directly through MailChimp, the notifications don't happen. How do I still get notifications even when they have been added with Zapier?

Note that it must be doable from a free MailChimp and Zapier account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply make a new Zap in Zapier:

> Trigger: MailChimp subscriber
>
> Action: Send Outbound email. - Get it to send to your email address.

Done!